# Vlookup from different workbook (result is also in the other workbook)

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a code to perform the vlookup in H column in workbook 1, the match is from column A in a separate workbook and the result is column B for the other workbook.
No idea how to go about this 
could someone please help

```
Sub y()

Dim rw As Long, x As Range, v As Variant
Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook
Dim wsActiveSheet As Worksheet

Columns("H").Insert
    Range("H1") = "1st phase"

Set wsActiveSheet = Application.ActiveSheet
Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\OUROBOROS\Desktop\Goldratt\24-6-19\1st phase stores.xlsx") 'file with reference table
Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A300")

For rw = 2 To wsActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    v = Application.Match(wsActiveSheet.Cells(rw, "G").Value, x, 0)
    If IsNumeric(v) Then
        wsActiveSheet.Cells(rw, "H").Value = extwbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rw, "b").Value 'G is in the table
    Else
        wsActiveSheet.Cells(rw, "H").Value = "NA" ''G is NOT in the table
    End If
Next rw


    Dim LR As Long
Range("a1").EntireRow.Insert
    LR = Range("v" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("v1").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,v3:v" & LR & ")"

    LR = Range("v" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("w1").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,w3:w" & LR & ")"

    LR = Range("v" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("x1").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,x3:x" & LR & ")"

    LR = Range("v" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("y1").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,y3:y" & LR & ")"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be what you actually need because you were saying some columns on your question and there are totally different ones on your code. You can change the columns by chaning the numbers refering to them arr(i, X) the X is the column number.

```
Option Explicit
Sub y()

    Dim arrSource, arrLookUp
    Dim DictData As New Scripting.Dictionary 'Needs the Microsoft Scripting Runtime 'Tools->References
    Dim i As Long
    Dim extwbk As Workbook


    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet") 'Change MySheet for your sheet name(the one were you are doing the vlookup)
        .Columns("H").Insert
        .Range("H1") = "1st phase"
        arrSource = .UsedRange.Value 'store the whole sheet inside the array
    End With

    Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\OUROBOROS\Desktop\Goldratt\24-6-19\1st phase stores.xlsx") 'file with reference table
    With extwbk.Sheets("MyOtherSheet") 'Change MyItherSheet for the name of the sheet holding the reference table
        arrLookUp = .UsedRange.Value 'store the whole sheet inside the array
    End With
    extwbk.Close SaveChanges:=False 'close the file with the reference table (the data is already in the array)

    'Create a dictionary holding the index for the lookup
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrLookUp) 'loop through the reference table
        If Not DictData.Exists(arrLookUp(i, 1)) Then 'check if the value in column A is not  duplicated
            DictData.Add arrLookUp(i, 1), arrLookUp(i, 2) 'add the matching value from column A with it's value in column B
        End If
    Next i

    'Loop through your original table to find the matches
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrSource)
        If Not DictData.Exists(arrSource(i, 7)) Then 'check if we have a match inside the dictionary for column G
            arrSource(i, 8) = "NA" 'if column G value is not found in the dictionary, column H will have a "NA"
        Else
            arrSource(i, 8) = DictData(arrSource(i, 7)) 'if column G value is found in the dictionary, column H will have column B from the other workbook
        End If
    Next i

    Dim LR As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet") 'Change MySheet for your sheet name(the one were you are doing the vlookup)
        .UsedRange.Value = arrSource 'drop back the array into the sheet
        .Range("a1").EntireRow.Insert
        LR = Range("v" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("v1").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,v3:v" & LR & ")"

        LR = .Range("v" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("w1").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,w3:w" & LR & ")"

        LR = .Range("v" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("x1").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,x3:x" & LR & ")"

        LR = .Range("v" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("y1").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(9,y3:y" & LR & ")"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: There is a problem with the matching, the new column is blank